# Concurrent write access to character device file

Tags: files, sysfs, character-device

I am wondering what happens when two processes write to a character device file at the same time.
Currently, I am mostly worried about /dev/spidev0.0 on a Raspberry pi.

If I assume correctly that it's the drivers task to deal with concurrent writes,
does the driver see which processes have written which data?
Or does the driver only see only continous data stream where all the concurrent writes get mixed in?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. The driver can certainly "see" which process is writing right now, but what do you expect it to do with this information? Whenever process A, or B, or C etc. writes to the device, a character is output, except if `spidev` uses some locking protocol.

Comment: So the driver reads and sends one byte from A, then one from B, then C, A and so on, until all streams are empty? Or does it empty every stream before going to the next? Is the resulting SPI stream ABCABCBBC or rather AABBBCCC?

Comment: I don't think the driver has a notion of "streams". It could wait until process A closes the device file, but I can't imagine it does that. However, according to the answer, it does write out an entire buffer without interference from other processes. The buffer has a max size of `bufsiz`, which is likely to be a rather small number.

Comment: In general, I would very much expect writes to be atomic wrt. each other. If one process writes `aaa` and another writes `bb`, the result better be either `aaabb`, or `bbaaa` (for non-seekable streams). POSIX dictates that for regular files and pipes up to some maximum write length (`PIPE_BUF`), and I'd be surprised if the same didn't apply to stream sockets (e.g. TCP) or "regular" UART serial ports on serious systems. (For regular files, the writes can of course overlap, but they still can't interleave.) Anyway, SPI isn't exactly a stream protocol, it has to guarantee intact transfers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Linux 5.4.97 kernel source, I see `drivers/spi/spidev.c`.  In that file, I see the function that handles write requests:

```c
ssize_t
spidev_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf,
                size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
        struct spidev_data      *spidev;
        ssize_t                 status = 0;
        unsigned long           missing;

        /* chipselect only toggles at start or end of operation */
        if (count > bufsiz)
                return -EMSGSIZE;

        spidev = filp->private_data;

        mutex_lock(&spidev->buf_lock);
        missing = copy_from_user(spidev->tx_buffer, buf, count);
        if (missing == 0)
                status = spidev_sync_write(spidev, count);
        else
                status = -EFAULT;
        mutex_unlock(&spidev->buf_lock);

        return status;
}
```

Note the call to `mutex_lock()` and `mutex_unlock()`.  A process calling `write()` on the character device will acquire the mutex, write all of its data, then unlock the mutex.  If there was some other writer that came along during that process, that writer would block on the call to `mutex_lock()` until the existing writer called `mutex_unlock()`.

Any writer that writes is guaranteed to write the entire buffer without interleaving from other writers.

Comment: so that's the callback called when some other process writes to the  /dev/spi... file? Just for my understanding: The mutex is really being locked by the spi driver, not by the writing process? Does is make any difference whether the writing processes open and close the file or just keep it opened the whole time and write to it periodically?

Comment: The writing process invokes the `write()` system call on an open file descriptor associated with the character device.  That leads to the execution of the above function in the kernel to handle that operation. @DanielD.

Comment: With SPI, the writes aren't as much streaming bytes (as with a "regular" serial port or a TCP socket), but sending full messages (as with an UDP socket). The driver controls the chip select / chip enable lines too, and deactivates them between all `read()` and `write()` calls (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/spi/spidev.html). SPI devices can well depend on the chip enable to identify the start and end of a transfer. (Worse, they may require both writes and reads within the same transfer.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for taking your time and looking up the code, really helped me to understand things :)

Comment: what if the user process gets signaled (eg.SIGKILL) while in the kernel context? does the lock stop? or does the process waits until the syscall returns?